# installation directory of appium in mac

Tags: automation, appium

I have installed appium-1.5.1 from MAC terminal. The installation is ok but I need the path where it is installed for some reason. Can anyone please tell me where is the installation directory in?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you installed the GUI appium app (the app whose icon you can click in your Mac's Launchpad), then as orde suggested earlier, just see `/Applications/Appium.app`

But if you say you installed appium via your terminal, I'm going to take a guess that you installed it using npm. If you installed appium by typing something like `npm install -g appium`, then all the below is for you:

You can find the appium executable by typing this into your terminal:

```
which appium
```

the output of typing this command in your terminal should be something like this (the path may be different for you):

```
/usr/local/bin/appium
```

If 'which' gave you a filepath like this, then this path is your appium executable file (the file that is run if you type 'appium' into your terminal).

If you want to find appium's actual installed files, then take the path you just got above, and run the following command, replacing my path with yours:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/appium
```

the result of that command will look something like this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 qamacbook  admin  44 Apr 19 11:07 /usr/local/bin/appium -> ../lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js
```

the end of this line, after the arrow, is the location of your appium installation relative to the executable file. In my example, the full installation is therefore located at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/`

Hope it helps!

Comment: please clarify where is "../lib/node_modules/..".  I would like to find out complete directory path

Comment: excellent explanation, thanks for your sharing knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here: `/Applications/Appium.app`.  Just change directory to root from your home directory (i.e. `cd /`), and you'll see the `Applications` directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Terminal type command 'which appium'

It will locate where appium executable is present.

2. Access the directory and type 'ls -lrt' command

It will display you the linked path of main.js file.

Copy the path in withAppiumJS(new File("<>"))

https://www.blogger.com/blog/post/edit/3033411347863264315/7244750496917206581