# Run appium automation without code-signing

Tags: appium

Why can't I run an appium script on an ios app that has not been signed with a developer certificate?  For example, I would like to run a basic script with app like Yelp, but I cannot do this because the app is not code-signed.  Would this be possible if I have the app's bundle identifier but still not signed.

The specific error:

```
[Xcode] 2018-07-06 17:00:40.418 xcodebuild[13062:696914] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/shriamin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f7f693586e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
[Xcode] 2018-07-06 17:00:40.418 xcodebuild[13062:696914] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted}
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED **
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
```

NOTE: Running on a real-device.

Comment: Why do you think that's the reason it won't run?  Is there a specific error message?

Comment: Please provide some stacktrace, some code examples.

Comment: @BillHileman well that's how i remembered it being, but if I'm wrong please tell me I'm wrong...I DO recall that certain "default apps" like Maps did NOT require signing, ONLY the bundle identifier.  The rest require code-signing as far as I can remember.

Comment: I've never encountered this but I've only ever worked with Android apps, not ios.  Are these ios apps?  What is the error you get when you try to run your scripts?  What environment are you running in?

Comment: It would appear that your question phrased differently was answered in another post earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186493/is-it-now-possible-to-automate-an-app-store-app-using-appium

Comment: That's what I thought, but it still doesn't answer WHY?

Comment: I think @vighneshpai answers that question below better than I could.  I upvoted his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer Code-signing is a way to make sure that, no un-identified developer do the coding and try to run the app on various devices. (they want the devs to register themselves) and avoid distribution of app outside the app store.

This is how it works when developer code signing is done, you will have to use the provision profile and certificate which include a finite set of devices authorized to run the apps which have these certificate and provision profiles.

Xcode IDE is built in such a way that, without these provision profile and certs, you will never be able to run on a physical device. That's why developer code singing is required.

Comment: i still don't get it.  if a dev says "my app is not distributed to system xyz", then no real user can run the app on that system - nevermind appium..  but if the app is signed-certified to work on system 123 then why would appium prevent me from running a script with that working config? why does appium care if the person who wants to run a script is also the owner of the app?  makes no sense.

Comment: Whata the exact erroe that you are getting? Tell me

Comment: WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Comment: As expected, this is not a problem of your app which is under test. To run the tests on iOS devices appium uses web deiver agent. This is not code signed. You can right click on appium app you are using > show package contents > search for an xcode project > you will see a couple of projects including web deiver. Now open web driver agent xcode project and use an apple developer account to code sign it. You can google about this.

Comment: i read about this error 65 on the xcuitest docs [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver).  I attempted to create a new keychain and then added this info to the capabilities dict, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I am using the appium node server, not the GUI application..how can I edit the xcode prj for the agent under these circumstances?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36720964/1289629 this question here has ur question abt installation directory. Go there and Use my method to get it working.

Comment: yes, this works.  The webdriverAgent app needs to be installed and signed for any kind of appium testing on a real device.  The documentation is terrible.

Comment: Glad that u could resolve ur problem. Thanks for upvote and accepting the answer.