# Is it now possible to Automate an App Store App using Appium

Tags: ios, automation, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

Historically, it was not possible to automate iOS app store apps using Appium (e.g. due to the Distribution Certificate used on all app store apps meaning you couldn't access the app via Appium).

Is this now possible in mid-2018 and if so does anyone know how to set it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not Automate an Appstore app using Appium.

To do automation testing on a ios app it should be signed with development certificate.

Comment: Thanks Durai.  Just found the same on the official Appium site: 
http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/platform-support/index.html

Comment: You can only use the apps which you have a development certificate signed IPA.

Answer (score 2):

You can launch almost any iOS system app if you know it's bundle identifier.

I use ruby:

```
def launch_app(bundle_id)
  @driver.execute_script('mobile: launchApp',{'bundleId': "#{bundle_id}"});
end

def terminate_app(app_path)
  @driver.execute_script('mobile: terminateApp',{'app': "#{app_path}"});
end
```

To launch App Store:

```
launch_app("com.apple.AppStore")
```